# My Delete Method is Splicing out the Last Item in My Array, Rather than the Selected Item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, splice

I am trying to remove an item from an array in my angular 2 app by utilizing the splice method. But right now, when I hover over the garbage icon for an item and click it, the last item in the array gets deleted, rather than the one I am clicking on. What do I need to adjust in my code to delete the current clicked item, rather than the last item in the array?

Here is my component info:

```
  zipcodes = [
    { id: 3, zipcode: '75201', city: 'Dallas' },
    { id: 8, zipcode: '75205', city: 'Dallas' },
    { id: 1, zipcode: '77001', city: 'Houston' },
    { id: 2, zipcode: '78703', city: 'Austin' },
  ];

  deleteZip() {
    console.log('Delete zip clicked...');
    this.zipcodes.splice(this.zipcodes.indexOf(this.zipcode), 1);
  }
```

And here's the relevant code from my component template/view:

```
<div *ngFor="let zipcode of zipcodes">{{zipcode.zipcode}} -- <span>{{zipcode.city}}</span><span class="delete-option" (click)="deleteZip()"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muirik,

Looks like the "this.zipcode" might not be the index you want to remove.

Consider passing in the index you want to remove like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let zipcode of zipcodes; let myIndex=index">{{zipcode.zipcode}} -- <span>{{zipcode.city}}</span><span class="delete-option" (click)="deleteZip(myIndex)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></span></div>
```

This passes the index to your method, which would now be:

```
deleteZip(zipIndex: number) {
    this.zipcodes.splice(zipIndex, 1);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks, Chrispy. I had forgotten that tracking the index in the *ngFor was the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: No problem! :)  glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the zipcode to your delete method

```
deleteZip(zipcode:any) {
    let index = this.zipcodes.indexOf(zipcode);
    if(index >= 0) {
        this.zipcodes.splice(index , 1);
    }
}
```

Then in you template

```
<div *ngFor="let zipcode of zipcodes">{{zipcode.zipcode}} -- <span>{{zipcode.city}}</span><span class="delete-option" (click)="deleteZip(zipcode)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></span></div>
```

Comment: Note that this line probably won't work: this.zipcodes.splice(zipcode, 1); as it's unlikely zipcode will be a valid index...

Comment: This worked, thanks. But it looks like I also need to track the index (as described by another commenter below), like this: 
<div *ngFor="let zipcode of zipcodes; let myIndex=index">
Once I added that this is working as desired. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @chrispy. I have edited to check for -1 index which could remove the last item

Comment: I don't really think you should track the index. see updated answer. which checks for the index and and checks whether it's a positive integer before attempting the splice.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that it can't find `this.zipcode`.
If `this.zipcodes.indexOf(this.zipcode)` returns `-1` (not found) then calling:

```
this.zipcodes.splice(-1, 1)
```

Will always remove and return the last item.